# Date countdown in PHP with IF and ELSES

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a countdown to an event for my church.

But when I test it, the further it goes is the response `1 day to go`, it never gets to `TODAY` even if the date has passed.

Any idea on what I have done wrong?

```
$days = ceil((strtotime("4/30/2016 3AM") - time())/(60*60*24));
if ($days > "1") { echo "$days days to go"; }
elseif ($days = "1") { echo "$days day to go"; }
elseif ($days = "0") { echo "TODAY!"; }
else { echo "You're late"; }
```

Comment: Use double equals http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are assigning the value `"1"` and `"0"` respectively to the `$days` variable. If you want to compare a `String` you should use `==` so in your case the code does not work because the `ifelse` statement will always stop on elseif `($days = "1")`.

Comment: Great, poblem solved! Thank you!